# touchesBegan cancel UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a general touchesBegan in my viewcontroller

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"--[%s:%d]",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__LINE__);
}
```

This seems to cancel the UISwipeGestureRecognizer. (not fired)

```
   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
        [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    swipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;

    swipeLeft.cancelsTouchesInView=NO;
    swipeRight.cancelsTouchesInView=NO;
swipeLeft.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
    swipeRight.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;

    self.viewSwipe.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [self.viewSwipe addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
    [self.viewSwipe addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

Any idea? :)

Answer (score 0):

`touchesBegan::` gets called before any gesture recognizers, and will indeed override them.

If you wish to support both tap and swipe on the same view, you can use a UITapGestureRecognizer, and call requireGestureRecognizerToFail.

So, add the following to the bottom of your code sample:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[tapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail swipeLeft];
[tapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail swipeRight];
```